# Python: __init__ in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking

I have a file called `main.py`,it call other .py file like `Auth.py`.
In `main.py`,I have a repeat loop,It call `work` function in other py.
But I found that once it call the function,the `__init__` will be run once.
I only need it to run the `__init__` when it import.How can I achieve that?

**main.py**

```
from Auth import Auth
from Group import Group
from SliverBox import SilverBox
from Task import Task

while (1):
    Auth().work()
    Group().work()
    SilverBox().work()
    Task().work()
```

**Auth.py**

```
import json
import time
import base64
import requests
from Log import Log
from Curl import Curl
from config import config
from Base import openssl_public_encrypt,arrange_cookie

class Auth():

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = int(time.time())

    def work(self):
        if self.lock > int(time.time()):
            return

        if config["Token"]["ACCESS_TOKEN"] == "":
            self.loginPassword()
        else:
            self.loginToken()

        self.checkCookie()

        self.lock = int(time.time()) +3600
```

Comment: why are you instantiating `Auth()` in your loop? Each time you instantiate it, it will run `__init__` again. That's what `__init__` *is for*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the creation/initialization and use of your objects:

```
auth = Auth()
group = Group()
....
while (1):
    auth.work()
    group().work()
    ....
```